# Checking and returning a Boolean value

Tags: java

Wondering how to do this, wish is important to my work. This is actually the missing piece and would appreciate if someone could give me the logic I have a field (in Column) made up of many integer values e.g:

```
122 
123
124 
...
```

I want to use another field having **same but fewer** values to check if it exists in the in the 1st first column. If a value exists, output `yes`, and if it does not, output `no`. So, the final output should be something like:

```
122  yes
123  no
124  yes
```

What I mean is something like this:

```
Field 1   Field 2
   1        3
   2        6
   3        8
   4    
   5
   6
   7
   8
    OUTPUT
 Field 1   Buy
   1       No
   2       No
   3       Yes
   4       No
   5       No
   6       Yes
   7       No
   8       Yes
```

check if the values of field 2 are in field 1..if a value is available, return yes..if not available return ...No

Comment: I don't understand the logic you are trying to implement. Why are 122 and 124 "yes" while 123 is "no"?

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you having trouble with?  What is your question?

Comment: very poorly framed post. I don't understand it at all. Please elaborate. where is the second "field" ? You have not given that part...how do we know which one is yes which one is no. I don't even understand what you're depicting a field as in your example.

Comment: So sorry guys..the entire task is complicated..But please bare with me.'  @Eran..Why are 122 and 124 "yes" while 123 is "no"?.. It means the if 123 exist in both fields, return yes, 123 is No because it it is in column 2 but not in column 1. @ anu....Field 1 contains 122, 123,124....Field 2 contains 122, 124..The aim is to check if the value of Field 2 are in Field 1. If a value in Field 2 is also in Field 1, return yes, else return No

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values in your first column in a map and check for the second column whether its value is present in map or not.
If it is present then, you can print yes else no

Answer (score 0):

You can put values of your second column into a set, then check each value of the first column whether it's in the set. If yes, print yes, else print no.

In java, you can use Collection class to implement your program. Some examples can be find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm). The second link offers a working example, a minimal modification is all you need to adapt it to your problem.

Comment: And that is exactly the problem, how do I do it.I am new a java...what would take you 10 minutes would take me 2 days without results. The issue is that using java in my task is unavoidable. Can I have a sample please.

Comment: If you don't want to code and just need a working program, I suggest you [this site](http://www.rent-acoder.com/)